# I am using a Data List in Visual Studio, but I want to have a HyperLinkField in it

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, datalist

I need to have a hyperlink field in 1 of the data items inside of the datalist. How should I go about to do this?

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductId" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId={0}" 
    DataTextField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" />
```

This is the field I would like to put inside one of the datalist item.

Please advise. Thanks.

My data list looks like:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" DataKeyField="ProductId" RepeatColumns="3">
    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <ItemStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        ProductId:
        <asp:Label ID="ProductIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>' />
        <br />
        ProductName:
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductId" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId={0}"
            DataTextField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" />
        <br />
        SalesItem:
        <asp:Label ID="SalesItemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SalesItem") %>' />
        <br />
        ProductCategory:
        <asp:Label ID="ProductCategoryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductCategory") %>' />
        <br />
        NormalPrice:
        <asp:Label ID="NormalPriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NormalPrice") %>' />
        <br />
        PromotionPrice:
        <asp:Label ID="PromotionPriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PromotionPrice") %>' />
        <br />
        QuantityOnHand:
        <asp:Label ID="QuantityOnHandLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuantityOnHand") %>' />
        <br />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
</asp:DataList>
```

As you can see, i tried to put the hyperlink into the "Product Name" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Since you decided to ask here, I assume you have tried but failed to show the link in the datalist. Please show us what the datalist looks like and how you have tried to add the link...

Comment: My datalist looks like:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="ProductNameLink" 
    runat="server"
    NavigateUrl='<%# "ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId=" + Eval("ProductId").ToString() %>'
    Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'/>
```